# how to get rate limit values in JIRA REST API of /rest/api/3/field

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

we are getting 429 error on making rest api (/rest/api/3/field)

**name:"AxiosError",
reason:"Too Many Requests",
code:"ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
status:429,**

Below is the response headers
[image]

**How to get api limit and when we should make next call?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'get' the rate limit, you can only detect that you have hit limit when you get the first 429 error code.

A 429 response is Atlassian's way of saying *"If you won't respect our Acceptable Use Policy and you overload our systems, we'll stop you here."*

This is all well documented by Atlassian. Just Google *'jira cloud rest api rate limit'* ...The first result returned is their documentation that explains all the techniques you are supposed to use in the first place to not overload an endpoint, then what what happens next if you didn't do what you were supposed to do and start getting 429 errors.